# react-native checkbox, how do I check or uncheck by using checkbox when I press the checkbox?

Tags: checkbox, react-native

I would like to know how I can check and uncheck checkbox in react-native?

Do I need to use getInitialState and props? or just need to use checkbox and onPress?

Comment: are you creating your own checkbox?

Comment: as long as I can create a box that I can check when I press the box and uncheck when I press again, I do not mind the way, but I would like to know from the beginning because Im still pretty new to this language

Comment: check my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick and very simple implementation.

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

class MyCheckbox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            checked: false
        }
    }

    toggle() {
        this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.toggle.bind(this)}>
                <View>
                    {this.state.checked ?
                         <Icon name="angle-left" size={16} color='#000000' />
                         :
                         null
                    }
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
    }
}
```

Use the onPress function to update the state of the component. set its state as either checked = true or checked = false.

Comment: this is in es6, by the way.

Comment: what to do for multiple checkbox on click of particular item .

Answer (score -1):

You can use [this component](https://github.com/sconxu/react-native-checkbox) or write a custom checkbox with images.

Comment: hello, thanks for the comment. mind if you can give me some examples? im still having trouble with it. it would be great if you can give example such as with one page you can see checkbox and if you click it check mark will disappear and once click again, it will appear.